# Rails 4: Access model from another controller's view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, rails-activerecord

I am relatively new to rails and am writing a website for a store where I have a `locations_controller` for the multiple store locations and I also have a `potentialClients_controller` for when people fill out a form, requesting more information using their name, email, etc.

Through my `locations_controller` I have several views for each location, and in the location's view, I want to include a form that accesses the `potentialClients_controller`.

Is this done through relationships or some other way?  The view below throws `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` error because in this view, `@potential_client` is `nil`.

**How do I make `@potential_client` accessible?**

**locations/Newton.html.erb**

```
<div class="main-content">
    <h1>Newton, MA</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="form-container">
            <%= form_for @potential_client do |f| %>

                <%= f.label :name %>
                <%= f.text_field :name %><br />

                <%= f.label :email %>
                <%= f.email_field :email %><br />

                <%= f.label :phone %>
                <%= f.number_field :phone %><br />

                <%= f.label :message %>
                <%= f.text_field :message %><br />

                <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can try and pass in Potential_client.new or whatever your model name is.

Comment: This doesnt work becasue its looking for the method in the `locations_controller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumptions:**

- You have a model `potential_client.rb` having a code:

  ```
  class PotentialClient < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location
    # ..
    # ..
  end
  ```
- You have a model `location.rb` having a code:

  ```
  class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :potential_clients
    # ..
    # ..
  end
  ```

**Solution:**

locations_controller.rb

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
   def newton
     @location = Location.find(1) # if your location with id=1 is newton
     # or if you are using an attribute to identify the location, i.e. name, then uncomment the following instead, and remove the line above
     # @location = Location.find_by(name: 'newton')
   end
end
```

locations/newton.html.erb

```
<div class="main-content">
    <h1>Newton, MA</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="form-container">
            <%= form_for @location.potential_clients.build do |f| %>

                <%= f.label :name %>
                <%= f.text_field :name %><br />

                <%= f.label :email %>
                <%= f.email_field :email %><br />
                <%= f.label :phone %>
                <%= f.number_field :phone %><br />

                <%= f.label :message %>
                <%= f.text_field :message %><br />

                <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Recommended Solution:**

- rename `potentialClients_controller` to `potential_clients_controller`
- `locations_controller.rb`

  ```
  LocationsController < ApplicationController

    def newton
      @location = Location.find(1) # if your location with id=1 is newton
      @potential_client = @location.potential_clients.build
    end

    # i.e.
    def einstein
      @location = Location.find(2) # if your location with id=2 is einstein
      @potential_client = @location.potential_clients.build
    end

    # ..
    # ..
  end
  ```
- `locations/newton.html.erb`

  ```
  <div class="main-content">
      <h1>Newton, MA</h1>
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="form-container">
              <%= form_for @potential_client do |f| %>

                  <%= f.label :name %>
                  <%= f.text_field :name %><br />

                  <%= f.label :email %>
                  <%= f.email_field :email %><br />

                  <%= f.label :phone %>
                  <%= f.number_field :phone %><br />

                  <%= f.label :message %>
                  <%= f.text_field :message %><br />

                  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

              <% end %>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

**Better Recommended Solution:**

- DRY up you methods by removing `def newton` and `def einstein` (etc) in your `locations_controller`. Instead of these methods that are statically defined, it is better to use a single method to remove duplicate code: i.e. `def new_potential_client` and also of course the `def create_potential_client` actions. In these actions, you identify if the `location` is `newton` or `einstein` by passing the `params[:id]`. I.E. your url might be something like `/locations/9876/new_potential_client`
- Same as the line just above, but instead of `/locations/9876/new_potential_client`, you might want `/locations/newton/new_potential_client` instead. Then, you would need slugs for this. One gem I use is [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

**Best Recommended Solution:**

- Use Shallow-Nested Resource Routing having RESTful implementation. More info [HERE](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting)
- If you use Shallow-Nested Resource Routing, your url would look something like `/locations/9876/potential_clients/new`
- Or if using `friendly_id` slug names, url will look like `/locations/newton/potential_clients/new`

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!  I will work on getting the recommended solution to work, but for now I get the following error when I use your solution: `NoMethodError in LocationsController#newton` and  `undefined method 'potential_clients' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @JeremyThomas, you tried the `Recommended Solution` that resulted that error? or just the `Solution`? If by using just the simple `Solution`, and you encountered that error, it means that in `locations/newton.html.erb`, @location is Nil / Nothing / No Value. You need to make sure that in your `locations_controller#newton`, the `@location` will have a value

Comment: I updated the `Solution`  part of my answer, by explicitly adding what would look like in your `locations_controller.rb`

Comment: Thanks a lot !  I will try to follow your instructions for a better way to accomplish this, but the current solution works!

Comment: One more question.. If I create a `potential_client` using the form and my model has a `location_id` field to link to the location, how can I access the `location_id` from within my `potential_client_controller`?

Comment: if you have a potential_client Object (regardless where it is: it may be in potential_clients_controller, locations_controller, view file, or in model), you can immediately access its associated location by appending the `.location` which is a Location object, or you can just simply append `.location_id` if you just care about the ID of the location. You can also use `.location.id`. So, your code would look like `@potential_client.location` or `@potential_client.location.id` or `@potential_client.location_id`

Comment: In case you still don't know, you can just simply create any variable in the controller with an `@` at the start whatever you wish to name it. Say `@asdfzxcv = Location.find(1)`. You can also use `asdfzxcv = Location.find(1)`, but without the `@` at the start. To compare these two, for simplicity, `@` variables are accessible in the view files, while those without `@`, you cannot access in the view file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102401/discussion-between-jeremy-thomas-and-jay-ar-polidario).

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy, have you tried this?

`<%= form_for @potential_client do |f| %>`

and in the controller action set `@potential_client = PotentialClient.new`

Might be missing something but seems to be the most straightforward way to do this.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it.  In my `potentialClients_controller` I have `@potential_client = PotentialClient.new`, but this view is looking in my `locations_controller` which is why it's not finding it.  In my location model I've added `has_many :potential_clients` and in my potential clients model I've added `belongs_to :location` but still no luck